# Go defer - open and copy files in a loop

Tags: go

If I'm opening a file inside a `for` loop and will be finished with it at the end of that iteration, should I call `Close` immediately or trick `Defer` using a closure?

I have a series of filenames being read in from a `chan string` which have data to be copied into a zipfile. This is all being processed in a go func.

```
go func(fnames <-chan string, zipfilename string) {
    f, _ := os.Create(zipfilename)  // ignore error handling for this example
    defer f.Close()
    zf := zip.NewWriter(f)
    defer zf.Close()
    for fname := range fnames {
        r, _ := os.Open(fname)
        w, _ := zf.Create(r.Name())
        io.Copy(w, r)
        w.Close()
        r.Close()
}(files, "some name.zip")
```

Inside my `for` loop, would it be more idiomatic Go to write:

```
for fname := range fnames {
    func(){
        r, _ := os.Open(fname)
        defer r.Close()
        w, _ := zf.Create(r.Name())
        defer w.Close()
        io.Copy(w, r)
    }()
}
```

or should I continue with my code as-written?

Comment: I don't think one is more or less idiomatic than the other, but the first is simpler. It is idiomatic to check error values. When you add that code, the second approach will be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be checking your errors. I know this is meant to just be an example, but in this case it is important. If all you do is defer Close(), you can't actually check if there was an error during defer.

The way I would write this is to create a helper function:

```
func copyFileToZip(zf *zip.Writer, filename string) error {
    r, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer r.Close()

    w, err := zf.Create(r.Name())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer w.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(w, r)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return w.Close()
}
```

Once you add in all that error handling, the function is big enough to make it a named function. It also has the added benefit of checking the error when closing the writer. Checking the reader's error is unnecessary since that won't affect if the data was written.

Comment: Is it ok to both `defer w.Close()` and `return w.Close()`?

Comment: It depends on the type. Close can be called multiple times for most types. I happen to know (by reading the source) that calling Close twice is valid zip.Writer. An error is returned a second time, but that is during the defer so it doesn't matter.